# Trigger multiple add to basket buttons with one click using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to trigger multiple add to basket buttons on an off the shelf ecommerce platform. The server generates add to basket buttons with the following script:

Button 1:

```
<a id="productRepeater_ctl00_btnAddToBasket" class="btn addbutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('productRepeater$ctl00$btnAddToBasket','')">add to basket</a>
```

Button 2:

```
<a id="productRepeater_ctl01_btnAddToBasket" class="btn addbutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('productRepeater$ctl01$btnAddToBasket','')">add to basket</a>
```

Button 1:

```
<a id="productRepeater_ctl02_btnAddToBasket" class="btn addbutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('productRepeater$ctl02$btnAddToBasket','')">add to basket</a>
```

The platform script:

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['buyoffpage'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.buyoffpage;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
```

I want to be able to submit all of these buttons with one click on a separate jQuery button. The script I've got so far only submits the first one:

```
$("body").append('<div id=\"submitAll\"><a href=\"#\">HIT ME</a></div>');
$('#submitAll').click(function(e) {
   __doPostBack('productRepeater$ctl00$btnAddToBasket', 'productRepeater$ctl01$btnAddToBasket','productRepeater$ctl02$btnAddToBasket');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the forms aren't submitted via AJAX or something similar, you won't be able to submit all of them. If you are using AJAX you could do something like this:

```
var submitAll = $('<a href="javascript:;" />').html('HIT ME').click(function(){

      $('.addbutton').trigger('click');

});
$('body').append($('<div id="submitAll" />').append(submitAll));
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll want todo something like this...(you'll have to play with this as its not a complete solution)

```
function submitAll(){
  //your submit code
}

$(".btn.addbutton").each(function(a){
  //first clean up old junk
  a=$(a)
  a.removeAttr('href');
  //add a custom event call
  a.bind('submitAll', submitAll )
});

//fire custom events
$('#submitAll').trigger('submitAll')
```